# how to display checkbox in each row using vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

how to display checkbox in each row using vuejs, and i need to pass those checked items to a function for further process.
i tried but not working properly. i have given code below with api data output.

i need to pass selected id's to on().

```
        <va-card style="margin-top:20px">
         <table  style="width:100%;border:2px">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Pole ID</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                   <th>     
                    <label class="form-checkbox">
                      <input type="checkbox" v-model="selectPole"  >
                      <i class="form-icon"></i>
                    </label>
                  </th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr v-for="pole in streetInfo">
                  <td style="font-weight:bold">{{pole.pole}}</td>
                 <td>{{pole.address}}</td>
                  <td>       
                   <label class="form-checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" :value="pole.pole" v-model="selectedStreetLight">
                <i class="form-icon"></i>
                </label>
              </td>
             </tr>
           <va-button  @click="On()" class="my-0">ON</va-button>
            <va-button   @click="Off()" class="my-0">OFF</va-button>
            </tbody>
           </table>
          </va-table>
       </va-card>
```

//api Data output

```
        [
          {
            "address": "Jayanagar 4th Block Banglore", 
            "pole": "BNG-JAY-137-003",
            "select":false
          }, 
          {
            "address": "Jayanagar 5th Block Banglore", 
            "pole": "BNG-JAY-137-004",
            "select":false
          }, 
          {
            "address": "Jayanagar 6th Block Banglore", 
            "pole": "BNG-JAY-137-005",
            "select":false
          }
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <tr v-for="(index,pole) in streetInfo">
          <td style="font-weight:bold">{{pole.pole}}</td>
         <td>{{pole.address}}</td>
          <td>       
           <label class="form-checkbox">
          <input @change="change(index)" type="checkbox" :value="pole.pole" v-model="selectedStreetLight">
        <i class="form-icon"></i>
        </label>
      </td>
```

here i changed `(index,pole) in streetInfo` and `@change="change(index)`

and make a change(index) method and put what ever you want.

```
change(index)
{
    this.streetInfo[index].select=!this.streetInfo[index].select;
}
```

I believe this will help

Comment: to select all make another method and put a loop inside the method and make them all true and false, vise versa